# Connecting my Android service with the db

Tags: android, database, service

Hi i'm working on a service that collect data from sensor and save a fast fourier trasform in to the db, but when i press the red phone button (to make the screen black) it don't save anything. Any idea?

In addition i noticed that when i stop the service, it continues to read sensors, how should I do?

This is the code that i use to connect and start the service:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            myService = (IMyService) service;
            myService.set(toRec,CAMPIONI_FFT);
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        }
    };

    void doBindService() {
        bindService(new Intent(SensorsState.this, 
                SensorService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    void doUnbindService() {
        if (mIsBound) {
            // Detach our existing connection.
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        doUnbindService();
    }
```

And this is my Service (public recClass recc; is the class that manage the db):

```
public class SensorService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
private MyServiceBinder myServiceBinder = new MyServiceBinder();
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
public float[] dataBuffer;
public boolean mIsStarted = false;
public FourierClass fft;
public recClass recc;
public String toRec;
public int camp;
MediaPlayer player;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return myServiceBinder; // object of the class that implements Service interface.
}
public class MyServiceBinder extends Binder implements IMyService {
    public void set(String tr, int cp) {
        toRec = tr;
        camp = cp;
        fft = new FourierClass(camp);
        mIsStarted = true;
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");


    // Get the SensorManager 
    mSensorManager= (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
            mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    recc =  new recClass(this);
    recc.open();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    mIsStarted = false;
    recc.close();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    mIsStarted = true;
}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {    // SensorEventListener
    Sensor sens = event.sensor;
    if ((sens.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) && mIsStarted){
            fft.add((float)Math.sqrt((event.values[0]*event.values[0])+(event.values[1]*event.values[1])+(event.values[2]*event.values[2])));   // Add value to the fft
            dataBuffer = fft.calculate();
            if (dataBuffer != null){
                for (int i=0; i<fft.camp;i++){
                    if (toRec != getString(R.string.nuovo))
                        recc.addValue(toRec, dataBuffer[i]);
                }
            }
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Thanks

Valerio

Answer (score 1):

You need a WakeLock see [this tutorial](http://pdk.android.com/online-pdk/guide/power_management.html#androidPowerWakeLockExample) for details

Comment: But if i try to play a song it play while the screen is black, why it don't save in to the db but it play the song?

Comment: I tried this:

pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"wlTag");
wl.acquire();

but it crash on wl.acquire();

Comment: PS: I added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> on my manifest and it don't crash but it don't save data to the db